# Get top 20 results for users in mySQL

Tags: mysql

How to get: The top 20 universities in terms of the total amount of awards they received?
[image]
I've tried and it only gives me 1 record??

```
SELECT sum(amount), org
FROM iis
ORDER BY award
LIMIT 0, 20;
```

Comment: How many records are in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you're asking for the sum of ALL universities. You need to use a `GROUP BY` clause to specify that you want it per university:

```
SELECT SUM(amount), org
FROM iis
GROUP BY org
ORDER BY SUM(amount) DESC
LIMIT 0, 20;
```

Comment: Kudos to you, after 4 replies

Comment: Just noticed my ORDER BY clause wasn't correct, so I fixed it. (Hat tip to BrokenGlass)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `ORDER BY award DESC` with a `GROUP BY`

> The default sort order is ascending,
>   with smallest values first. To sort in
>   reverse (descending) order, add the
>   DESC keyword to the name of the column
>   you are sorting by

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

You need a grouping, otherwise you will only get one result, also you want to order by an aggregate column (sum of all amounts for a given organization) so you have to give it a name:

```
SELECT sum(amount) as total, org
FROM iis
GROUP BY org
ORDER BY total desc
LIMIT 0, 20;
```